# How to persist entities when one has two parents

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Here's my situation:

Framework Symfony 4, using Doctrine(version).

I have three entities : A, B and C.
Entity A has a OneToMany relationship with B, and a OneToMany relationship with C.
Entity B has a OneToMany relationship with C.

In a form, I have a collectionForm about entity C embedded in a collectionForm about entity B.
Adding entities B & C is optional in the form.

However, when trying to add entity C (and therefore entity B), seeing as entity C has two parents (A & B), doctrine fails to know in which order to persist those, and gives the following error :

> A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\EntityC#entityB' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\EntityB@0000000010cd7f460000000077359844. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\EntityB#__toString()' to get a clue.

How do I tell doctrine to persist entity A first, then B and then C in this case ?

So far, I've tried removing the OneToMany relationship between B and C, without any luck, and adding a ManyToOne relationship in entityC for entity B.
I feel if I could bypass this relationship between B and C this could work, but I don't know how.

EntityA :

```php
class entityA extends BaseEntityA {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EntityB", mappedBy="entityA", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="entityA_id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $entitiesB;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EntityC", mappedBy="entityA", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="entityA_id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $entitesC;

...

    /**
     * Add EntityB entity to collection (one to many).
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\EntityB $entityB
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\EntityA
     */
    public function addEntityB(\App\Entity\EntityB $entityB)
    {
        $this->entitiesB[] = $entityB;
        $entityB->setEntityA($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add EntityC entity to collection (one to many).
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\EntityC $entityC
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\EntityA
     */
    public function addEntityC(\App\Entity\EntityC $entityC)
    {
        $this->entitiesC[] = $entityC;
        $vehicle->setEntityA($this);
        return $this;
    }
```

Entity B :

```php
class EntityB extends BaseEntityB {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EntityC", mappedBy="entityB", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="entityB_id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $entitiesC;

...

    /**
     * @param Collection $entitiesC
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setEntityC(Collection $entitiesC)
    {
        $this->entitiesC = $entitiesC;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add EntityC entity to collection (one to many).
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\EntityC $entityC
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\EntityB
     */
    public function addEntityC(\App\Entity\EntityC $entityC)
    {
        $this->entitiesC[] = $entityC;
        $entityC->setEntityB($this);
        $entityC->setEntityA($this->getEntityA());

        // Things I tried to remove the relationship between B and C
//        $this->getEntityA()->addEntityC($entityC);
//        $entityC->setEntityB($this);
        return $this;
    }
```

Entity C :

```php
class EntityC extends BaseEntityC {

// Somtehing I tried at some point
//    /**
//     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityB", inversedBy="entitiesC", cascade={"persist"})
//     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entityB_id", referencedColumnName="id")
//     */
//    protected $entityB;

...
}
```

I would like to persist this entities in the right order (A then B then C), using only one form if possible.

Comment: well you're probably calling `persist` for at least one of those entities. I would suggest you call it for all linked entities as well before you flush. doctrine should really take care of the rest for you. what you can't do, is link an entity and only persist one of those (there may be some dirty ways around this. don't do those). to state it more explicitly: the problem is, that you flush before all linked entities are persisted. the number of "parents" should be irrelevant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping.
The thing is, the entities are all persisted before the flush.
For now, I have managed to bypass it all by excluding all EntityC entities in the preReverseMap function of EntityAFormDataProvider.php, that way all entitieC are not persisted at the same time as the others, and i keep the EntitiesC in a new protected $tmpEntitiesC.

Then, in the postPersist, when entitesA & B are lushed, I assign the $entityC with $tmpEntitiesC in a foreach and persist them, then flush.
This way, all entitiesC are flushed after the others, and are saved in DB with all the ids.

Comment: I don't know if that is quite clear, but if any help is needed, I will post what I did as an answer, just let me know